# anaconda activate for modules

Tags: python, conda

I have problem with anaconda i want to install and activate the modules and library but i see this error:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated. Libraries may fail to load. To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation.

I DO the solution in anaconda website and but i cant again becase i cant activate enviroment 
I INSTALL it in drive D and change the direction in cmd to activate

Comment: Could you add some actual commands that you ran?

Comment: Please provide some more information. See [ask], [help/on-topic].